How to Enable/Disable Bluetooth or Location Services using Appium Python Client?
I am currently working on automated testing of mobile applications using the Appium Python client. In my test scenarios, I need to programmatically enable or disable Bluetooth and location services on the device under test (Android and/or iOS).
I have searched through the Appium Python client documentation and Stack Overflow threads, but I couldn't find clear instructions or examples on how to achieve this functionality using the Appium Python client.
Can someone provide guidance or code examples on how to enable/disable Bluetooth and location services using the Appium Python client? Specifically, I'm interested in:

Enabling/disabling Bluetooth on an Android device.
Enabling/disabling Bluetooth on an iOS device.
Enabling/disabling location services (GPS) on an Android device.
Enabling/disabling location services (GPS) on an iOS device.

I would appreciate any insights, tips, or code snippets that can help accomplish this task efficiently and reliably. Thank you!

I don't understand the question, do you want someone to write you how to click the button in python or what exactly are you looking for ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@mosaad , I am looking for code snippets
